# NoClassDefFoundError on GAE Standard

Tags: google-app-engine

My app on Google App Engine (GAE) Standard generates an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/joda/time/DateTime

The joda time library is actually packaged as part of the GAE SDK and if I check the libs that got uploaded, joda is present. So why would I get an exception about no class def found for joda?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

repackaged libraries cannot be used on GAE. You have to use the original files. So make sure your import statements are referencing those and not the repackaged ones.

Answer (score 0):

[There are two Environments for Java on Google App Engine: Standard and Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/).

Java on App Engine Standard:

> supports the standard public Java library (no whitelist).

You should use App Engine Flexible if you want to:

> Use any framework, library, or binary of your choice.